# Why a function I am sourcing in bash not access the environment variables I have set?

Tags: bash

I have some code that looks like this:

```
export AWS_REGION='us-east-1'
export CLUSTER_NAME='my_cluster'
export PROJECT_NAME='my_project'

source ./utils.sh

...additional functions...

annotate_cluster # comes from utils.sh
```

`annotate_cluster`, which comes from `utils.sh`, relies on the environment variable `PROJECT_NAME`.  However, when I run it, it complains `_utils.sh: line 60: FOO-${PROJECT_NAME^^}: bad substitution`.  Why can it not access the environment variable I have set?

Comment: That error would arise if bash is running in posix mode (eg, invoked as `sh`)

Comment: "bad substitution" doesn't mean the variable doesn't exist; it means the shell doesn't recognize the `^^` syntax. That does indeed imply that you're running `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: It's a syntax error, not an environment issue.

Comment: (could also be too old a version of bash; that's a relatively recent feature, not found in bash 3.x; does one entrypoint use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` while the other one uses `#!/bin/bash`?).

Comment: But I am running it in bash?  I am doing `bash ./my_file.sh` and have been this entire time...

Comment: Add `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to your script. What does it say?

Comment: Solved it--thanks, @CharlesDuffy.  Apparently the default bash version on Mac is indeed quite old.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: _nod_. That's unfortunately deliberate -- Apple doesn't consent to be bound by the GPLv3 license that newer versions of bash are distributed under.